# Can I change my .ejs file to .html to make it work with Node.js and Express?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I have a index.html and wanted to link it to a twitter.ejs page. I was unsuccessful and now I am wondering if I can just change the extension from ejs to html. I tried to do it, but it does not work. Does only Node.js/Express work with a .ejs file?

My code trying to redirect from index.html to twitter.ejs: http://jsfiddle.net/1moj4v07/4/

**index.html**

```
<li><a href="/twitter">Tweet!</a></li>
```

**script.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser= require('body-parser')
const app = express();
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
var router = express.Router();

var db

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://name:password@cluster0-shard-00-00-fquoc.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-fquoc.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-fquoc.mongodb.net:27017/twitter?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin', (err, database) => {
  if (err) return console.log(err)
  db = database
  app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('listening on 3000')
  })
})

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

var path = require('path')


app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  db.collection('tweets').find().toArray((err, result) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err)
    res.render('twitter.ejs', {tweets: result})
  })
})

app.get('views/', (req, res) =>{
  res.render(views,local)
})

app.get('/twitter',function(req,res){
    res.render('twitter', {});
});

app.post('/tweets', (req, res) => {
  db.collection('tweets').save(req.body, (err, result) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err)
    console.log('saved to database')
    res.redirect('/')
  })
})
```

Folder structure

```
 twitter
    ├── views
    |   └── twitter.ejs
    |   
    ├── public
    |   └── styles.css
    |
    ├── index.html
```

Comment: What problem did you run into? Were there any error messages with your attempt?

Comment: @AndrewLohr When I try to click on the link from index.html to twitter.ejs, I get "Your file was not found". I go from file:///Users/name/twitter/index.html to file:///twitter. I followed tutorials on how to link to ejs files, but no luck.

Comment: twitter.ejs and index.html should both be in the `public` folder since that is where you state your static assets are `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));`

Comment: @AndrewLohr I just edited my post to show how my folder structure looks like. I thought I was supposed to use that to use my .css file in /public folder. So the linking does not work correctly because of that line? It works correctly when I view it on my localhost:3000. I put ´app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));´ instead of the line you just quoted, but it still doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

> I have a index.html and wanted to link it to a twitter.ejs page. I was unsuccessful and now I am wondering if I can just change the extension from ejs to html. I tried to do it, but it does not work. Does only Node.js/Express work with a .ejs file?

Express does indeed support formats other than `.ejs`, such as `.html` like you've asked, you'll just need to setup a new View Engine to support this. However, it looks like you have a number of other issues related to the structure of your Node application and the way your routes are loading its views.

To get a `.html` file rendered via Express, you can use `res.render()` with HTML files by creating a new View Engine in Express and then using that. The only requirement is that `ejs` is installed via `npm i --save ejs`. We need the `ejs` package directly because you'll need the `renderFile()` function for our new `html` view engine. Once you make the below change you can use `res.render()` to render a `.html` file.

This approach will not break data injection using EJS since `renderFile()` is still being used. The whole point of this approach is to continue getting EJS functionality if needed but, it will also render standard HTML as well all with one View Engine.

You also have a number of things that don't make sense in the given code along with a bad structure of your views.

- `index.html` isn't being served
- `twitter.ejs` is returned at the root of the app
- `app.get('views/')` uses a `views` variable that is never defined

I've given a new Express Server setup and Project Directory Structure

---

Folder Structure for App

```
/public
  /styles
    styles.css
/views
  index.html
  twitter.html
server.js
package.json
```

Updated Express Server

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const MongoClient = require('monogdb').MongoClient
const path = require('path')

const app = express()
let db

MongoClient.connect('<connectionString>', (err, database) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err)
  }

  db = database
  app.listen(3000, () => console.log('listening on 3000'))
})

app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile)
app.set('view engine', 'html')
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true})
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

// When at the base of the application, return /views/index.html
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  return res.render('index')
})

// When GET /twitter is requested, get tweets from DB 
// and render /views/twitter.html
app.get('/twitter', (req, res) => {
  db.collection('tweets').find().toArray((err, tweets) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
      return res.sendStatus(500)
    }

    return res.render('twitter', {tweets})
  })   
})
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining. My idea was to change .ejs to .html so that I could link directly from my index.html, like ´<li><a href="twitter.html">Tweet!</a></li>´ instead of ´<li><a href="/twitter">Tweet! (uten db)</a></li>´ (that I just couldn't make it work). I tried your way as and it still doesn't work with the second code quote. If I understood correctly, I can change the extension to .html and use the code to still make ejs work?

Comment: @J.Doe I've updated my answer for your updated question

Comment: Thank you! When running on localhost, the file showed when I clicked on it! But it did not work when I opened index.html in the web browser and then clicked on the link. Any idea why? Also now I have another problem: I am going to upload these files on a webserver that requires I have a index.html in the root-folder. Any idea what keywords I can look up to find a solution? Don't really know what kind of problem I can call it so I can search. Thank you so much again for a thorough explanation.

Comment: I just tried to make another index.html and link to the other index.html in the folder. I can go from the first index to the second index and then twitter link does not work. Only on localhost! hmm..